# What are the admissible functions for a rule of three and how to see it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

I remember of learning the rule of three in elementary school. These days I had a random thought and formulated it this way:

We have the values $x,f(x),x+h$ and we want to know the value of $f(x+h)$ in terms of the previous values. We write:

$$\cfrac{x}{x+h}=\cfrac{f(x)}{f(x+h)}$$

This yields:

$$f(x+h)=\cfrac{f(x)(x+h)}{x}\tag{1}$$

I used the symbol of function on purpose: When using a rule of three, we are assuming that there is a function that behaves in a certain way. The problem is that for certain functions, it would miss tremendously, for example: Suppose the unknown function is $f(x)=x^2$, a numerical example would be:

$$\cfrac{2}{4}=\cfrac{4}{x} \quad \quad\quad \quad\quad \quad 2x=16\quad \quad\quad \quad\quad \quad x=8$$

But $4^2=16$. My guess is that $f$ must be linear or affine but I'm not sure on how to see it. I did the following: Rewriting $(1)$:

$$f(x+h)x=f(x)(x+h)$$

As multiplication is well-defined and none of these quantities is $0$, then:

$$f(x+h)= f(x) \quad \quad \quad \quad x=x+h$$

Which implies that $h=0$, or:
$$f(x+h)= x+h \quad \quad \quad \quad x=f(x)$$

But this result left me confused. From gut feeling, this doesn't seems right. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong when you say :

> As multiplication is well-defined and none of these quantities is $0$, then: $f(x+h)= f(x) \quad \quad \quad \quad x=x+h$

Indeed, let us consider the equality $ 3 \times 4 = 6 \times 2$. From what you wrote one could conclude that $3 = 4$ or $6 = 2$. I guess you where thinking about the following (true) statement:

> if $a\times b = 0$, then $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.

However, it doesn't work if the right-hand term is not $0$.

---

Now, for your problem. The rule of three is related to the idea of *proportion*, and as such to *linearity*, and hence is only true for linear functions.

Let us assume $f$ is a function satisfying the "rule of three". We have $\frac{x}{x+h} = \frac{f(x)}{f(x+h)}$, which gives $\frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{f(x+h)}{x+h}$, for any $x$ and $h$. Which means that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is constant, ie $\frac{f(x)}{x} = a$ for some a.

All in all, we get that if $f$ follows the rule of three, then $f(x) = ax$.

Comment: Oh, I guess I wasn't clear. What I meant with that is that it would be absurd to think that $f(x+h)=f(x)$ and $x+h=x$ because it would force us to assume that $h=0$, but in the rule of three, we are not interested when $h=0$.

Comment: Oh, my bad. But then I'm not sure to understand what blocks you?

Comment: No, this is it. I was only a bit confused about this because it was a little bit different of what I was expecting.

Comment: Re-reading your proof, I don't understand how you get that (still on the same line) $f(x+h) = f(x)$. If you want, you can write $f(x+h) = f(x) + f(x)\frac hx$, but that's it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you have $a,b,c,d \neq0$ and $ab=cd$, then: $a=c, b=d$ or $a=d,b=c$.

Comment: Actually, no, see the example I provided: $2 \times 6 = 4 \times 3$. Yet $2 \neq 3$ and $2 \neq 4$.

Comment: Yes! I messed up, thanks. Why is $f(x)/x$ a constant?

Comment: Because $\forall x, h$, we have $f(x)/x = f(x+h)/(x+h)$. Especially, when $h = 1 - x$, let $a = f(1)/1$, then $\forall x, f(x)/x = a$, ie the ratio is a constant. Of course you'd have to pay attention to the case where $x=0$ for complete resolution, but no one cares about the rule of three when $x = 0$.

Comment: I was thinking something: Do you think the result I stated is valid for polynomials? One could do the following: $f(x+h)x=f(x)(x+h)$; $Ax=B(x+h)$, and hence, I guess the only possible non-trivial solutions would be: $A=x+h, B=x$ and $A=-(x+h), B=-x$.

Comment: You can have for instance $A = 3(x + h), B = 3x$, or any scalar multiplication. And I'd say that other higher-degree solutions are available, you can find the conditions on the coefficients if you put $A = a_nx^n + \dots + a_0$, and $B$ in the same way.